# Login user error (Unhandled Promise Error) HTTP HEADERS

Tags: reactjs, http, authentication, npm, header

Find attached my code am trying to login as a user and its giving me http promise headers error ((node:17772) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\codes\REACT-BLOG\blogbackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\codes\REACT-BLOG\blogbackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\codes\REACT-BLOG\blogbackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
at C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\codes\REACT-BLOG\blogbackend\routes\auth.js:39:25
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(node:17772) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2).

below is my code.

```
router.post ("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
        !user && res.status(400).json("wrong credentials!");

        const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
        !validated && res.status(400).json("wrong credentials!");

        const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
        res.status(200).json(others);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post ("/login", async (req, res) => {
try{
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
     return !user && res.status(400).json("wrong credentials!");

    const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    return !validated && res.status(400).json("wrong credentials!");

    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
    res.status(200).json(others);
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
}
```

});

Comment: This update still doesnt work